# Tools for conducting a Security Audit / Probe

Tags: windows, security

What are some good tools to run tests validating a Windows server Web & DB server is properly secure? Are there any tools which are comprehensive and will scan for all the popular known vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nikto](http://www.cirt.net/nikto2) is a good tool.

> Nikto is an Open Source (GPL) web
>   server scanner which performs
>   comprehensive tests against web
>   servers for multiple items, including
>   over 3500 potentially dangerous
>   files/CGIs, versions on over 900
>   servers, and version specific problems
>   on over 250 servers. Scan items and
>   plugins are frequently updated and can
>   be automatically updated (if desired).

Comment: I just tried out Nikto myself to scan a new webserver and it's very easy to set up and use. It did seem to think that the presence of a / path (and its many aliases) could indicate the existence of various troublesome programs, which was a pain to have to read through, but at least it appears to be quite thorough. Of course, the absence of a found vulnerability does not prove that there aren't any others, so I'd run as many different scanners as is feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the Nikto info. Very easy to run and I'm currently scanning some of my Windows IIS boxes with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Tools that will scan these type of vulnerabilities:

- [Nessus](http://www.nessus.org/nessus/)
- [Qualys](http://www.qualys.com/index.php)
- [eEye's Retina](http://www.eeye.com/html/products/retina/index.html)
- [NGS Software's Typhon III](http://www.ngssoftware.com/products/internet-security/ngs-typhon.php)

Comment: I used Nessus and was immediatley overwhelmed and couldn't actually get it to work what do you recommend for the programmer, who gets stuck managing a production environment?

Comment: If you can afford it, Qualys. It's a device that you can install in your data center in about 10-15 minutes. Setting up the scans are easy and done through a web interface. The training class is all of a day if you need it. And if necessary, you can scan your perimeter security using Qualys' external scanners.

Answer (score 1):

A newish tool for Web Application testing is [Cenzic Hailstorm](http://www.cenzic.com/products/software/overview/) It's quite extensive and will do a thorough job.
Nessus will also work quite well. You might want to read [Nessus Web App Testing PDF Guide](http://www.nessus.org/whitepapers/OWASP-05-2009-NessusWebAppTesting.pdf) and [Security Testing with Nessus](http://www.nessus.org/whitepapers/sec_test_sc3_nessus.pdf)
Paul Asadoorian from [pauldotcom.com](http://pauldotcom.com) is the product evangelist for nessus now, so he has quite a few good posts about using nessus to perform these kinds of tests.